# Querying countries per continent via Overpass API

Tags: query, overpass-api

I managed to get all states from a specific country by using the following code via the Overpass API:

```
[out:json][timeout:600];
area["name:en"="{country.Name}"]->.country;
(
   node[place~"state"](area.country);
);
out body;
```

But I really have no clue how I would be able to get all countries from a specific continent. How would you be able to do that?

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:admin%20level=2?uselang=en-GB